# showing an error message to prevent deletion/ sending an email

Tags: apex, trigger

I have 2 objects object 2 has a look up to object 1. If object 1 record is deleted it should send an email with the details provided in the code( which is working as expected). Now if object 2 has a record(>=0) associated to object 1 record then if user is trying to delete the object1 record it should show an error message to prevent deletion.

Please see the below code and help me out.

```
public with sharing class HelperTrigger {
  public String UserId {get; set;}
  // public static String getBaseUrl{get; set;}

    public static List<object1__c> sendEmail(List<object1__c> object1) {
         string currentRequestURL = URL.getCurrentRequestUrl().toExternalForm();
         Id UserId = userinfo.getUserId();
         String Username = [select Name, id from user where Id=:UserId].Name;

         system.debug('username ' +username);
        Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(2);

        //list of emails
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        set<Id> setIds = new set<Id>();
        List<Object2__C> ob = [SELECT Id,object1__c FROM Object2__C WHERE object1__c IN: setIds];
        map<Id, Integer> mapobject1__c = new map<Id, Integer>();
        //loop
        for(object1__c ob1 : object1){

            {
                setIds.add(ob1.Id);
            }

         for(object2__c obj2 :ob)
            {
                if(mapobject1__c.containsKey(obj.object1__c))
                    mapobject1__c.put(obj.object1__c, mapobject1__c.get(obj.object1__c)+1);
                else
                    mapobject1__c.put(obj.mapobject1__c, 1);
            }

            {
                if(mapobject1__c.containsKey(ob1.Id)){
                        so.Name.addError('Obj1 is Associated with obj2, cannot delete the record');
                    }

                //initiallize messaging method
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage singleMail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

                 singleMail.setToAddresses(new String[] {'xyz@gmail.com'});
                singleMail.setSubject('Deleted obj1 Alert');

                singleMail.setHtmlBody('URL : ' +currentRequestURL + '<br>' +'Record Deleted By: ' +Username + '<br>' +'Record ID: ' +so.Id + '<br>' + 'Contact Name: ' +obj1.Obj1__Contact__c );
                 singleMail.setSaveAsActivity(false);

                OrgWideEmailAddress[] owea = [select Id from OrgWideEmailAddress where Address = 'gsbhj@kja.org'];
if ( owea.size() > 0 ) {
                 singleMail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owea.get(0).Id);
             }

                //add mail
                emails.add(singleMail);
        }

        try{
        Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
            } catch(Exception e){system.debug('Email send failure on obj1 deletion ' + e);}


    }
    return obj1;
}
}
```

Comment: Raj -- You should [edit] the post to a) indicate that helper is called after Delete; b) change the names of object1 and object2 to something more relevant like `parentObj` and `childObj` ;  c) suppress all the lines that construct an email, they are not relevant to your issue; d) consider whether preventing deletes should be done in a before delete trigger so the after delete trigger only has legitimate deleted objects to work with

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through Object2__c after adding the Ids to your set.

So put this line of code:

```
List<Object2__c> ob = [SELECT Id,object1__c FROM Object2__C WHERE object1__c IN: setIds];
```

after the loop where you add the Ids to your set.

Comment: No luck ! I have an after delete trigger event on obj 1 for sending an email. Just want to add this point. @willard

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier way to do the enforcement of preventing deletion of parent object `Object1` if it has any child `Object2`:

- Go to Object2 in the Force.com UI and locate the relationship field that is the lookup from `Object2` to `Object1`
- Under Lookup Options, change the setting for `What to do if the lookup record is deleted?` to `Don't allow deletion of the lookup record that's part of a lookup relationship.`  This makes the relationship `restrictedDelete`. If the user attempts to delete the parent when there are children, SFDC will prevent it

Comment: Yes! but the objects are managed packages and i cant edit them. @cropredy

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you can edit the trigger on Object1 which you mentioned above then in that you can write a "Before Delete" and put the validation their.
If you need a sample code then let me know.